# Sending POST request on an already open url in python

Tags: python, forms, http-post

Basically I want to send a POST request for the following form.

```
<form method="post" action="">
449 * 803 - 433 * 406 = <input size=6 type="text" name="answer" />
<input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

What I basically want to do is read through the page, find out the equation in the form, calculate the answer, enter the answer as parameter to send with the POST request, but without opening a new URL for the page, as a new equation comes up every time the page is opened, hence the previously obtained result becomes obsolete. Finally I want to obtain the page that comes up as a result of sending the POST request. I'm stuck at the part where I have to send a POST request without opening a new URL instance. Also, I would appreciate help on how to read through the page again after the POST request. (would calling `read()` suffice?)

The python code I have currently looks something like this.

```
import urllib, urllib2

link = "http://www.websitetoaccess.com"
f = urllib2.urlopen(link)

line = f.readline().strip()
equation = ''
result = ''
file1 = open ('firstPage.html' , 'w')
file2 = open ('FinalPage.html', 'w')

for line in f:
    if 'name="answer"' in line:
        result = getResult(line)
    file1.write(line)

file1.close()

raw_params = {'answer': str(result), 'submit': 'Submit'}
params = urllib.urlencode(raw_params)
request = urllib2.Request(link, params)
page = urllib2.urlopen(request)

file2.write(page.read())
file2.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit puzzled, the POST request will always be a new separate request so I don't understand what you mean by "without opening a new URL instance" ... have you tried taking a look at what happens when you do what you're trying to do in this script manually? Like open developer console in Chrome, go to the network tab, toggle preserve log to on, delete history, and do what you're trying to do manually? Then replicate that in python? Also I recommend you try out the requests module, it makes things simpler than using urllib. Simply `pip install requests` (and `pip install lxml`).

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

url = 'http://www.websitetoaccess.com'
res1 = requests.get(url)
# do something with res1.content
# you could try parsing the html page with lxml
root = etree.fromstring(res1.content, etree.HTMLParser())
# do something with root, find question and calc answer?
post_params = {'answer': str(42), 'submit': 'Submit'}
res2 = requests.post(url, data=post_params)
# check res2 for success or content?
```

edit:

You're possibly experiencing some header issue or cookies issue. You might be receiving some session ID which enables the server to determine what question you received in the previous GET request. The POST request is a separate request from the previous GET request, it can't be combined to one single request. You should check the headers received from the previous GET request and/or try setting up session/cookies handling (easy to do if using requests, see https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/).

Comment: Problem with doing it manually in a web browser is that the form requires a machine driven response in order to authenticate properly as it has a timeout and fails to authenticate when trying to do it manually simply because a human cannot put the right answer in fast enough.

Comment: I tried using requests as you suggested, and I ran into the same issue. I believe with res2 in the code you provided above, it does start a new separate request (which in turn changes the question, therefore making my previously stored answer from the question in res1 wrong)

Comment: Is it possible this is a header issue or cookies issue? The POST request is a separate request from the previous GET request, it can't be combined to one request. You should check the headers and/or try using a session (easy to add if using requests, http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/).

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that last link really helped, turns out I just needed to create a new session from requests like so:

```
s = requests.session()
res1 = s.get(url)
```

And add this as the post request after

```
res2 = s.post(url, data=post_params)
```

I believe this achieves the result of storing the cookies from the get request and sending them with the post request, thus maintaining the same question as the previous get request. Many thanks for your help and assistance in this problem Loknar.

Comment: Hey, Thanks this is what I exactly wanted and it's working like charm.  
I belive this is exact answer to the question.